# WP7 allow orientation change but not the background image

Tags: windows-phone-7

My apps is planned to allow orientation change, however, I have background images (in pivot control that allow user to change the background images) that does not want to change the orientation. How should i implement that?

thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to add a Rotation Transform dynamically to offset the rotation of the background image when the orientation changes, as below :-

```
        private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitUp)
        {
            PivotBackground.RelativeTransform = null;
        }
        else
        {
            RotateTransform aRotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
            aRotateTransform.CenterX = 0.5; 
            aRotateTransform.CenterY = 0.5;
            aRotateTransform.Angle = 90;
            PivotBackground.RelativeTransform = aRotateTransform;
        }
    }
```

The XAML is defined as :-

```
        <controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
        <controls:Pivot.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Back.jpg"
                        x:Name="PivotBackground">
            </ImageBrush>
        </controls:Pivot.Background>
    </controls:Pivot>
```

Hope this helps.

Paul Diston

Comment: There could be a slight issue with the above if you want to display the SystemTray in your application because as the Orientation changes, the SystemTray rotates and requires a slightly greater width and therefore shifts the background image slightly. If you disable the SystemTray then this shift does not occur.